# Uniqueness of Seifert surfaces of knots

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, knot-theory

I know the theorem that Given a knot K in the 3-sphere, it has a Seifert surface S whose boundary is K. So, can we also say that for every unique Seifert surface   there is an unique knot and vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every Seifert surface $S$ has a unique associated knot $K$ (because $K$ is by definition just the boundary of $S$) but the converse is not true. There are certainly knots with more than one associated Seifert surface as a Seifert surface of a knot is dependant on the knot diagram being used for $K$ (when applying the standard Seifert algorithm anyway). This is why the genus of a knot is defined to be the *minimum* genus of all Seifert surfaces of the knot. Given a knot with a Seifert surface of genus $g$, it is always possible to construct a seifert surface of the same knot with genus $g+1$ using [surgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surgery_theory) as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert_surface#Genus_of_a_knot).

Comment: Note that this is true if you call two Siefert surfaces the same when they are "ambient isotopic".  However, two homeomorphic Siefert surfaces can belong two completely different knots.

Comment: @Carl, what is the difference between ambient isotopic Seifert surfaces and homeomorphic Seifert surfaces?

Comment: Ambient isotopy is a strictly stronger condition than homeomorphism between two surfaces with boundary. For example, a cylinder and a cyclinder with 'two twists' are homeomorphic, but they are not ambient isotopic. The associated links for these two surfaces are the unlink with two components and the Hopf link. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_isotopy for a full definition of ambient isotopy.

Answer (score 2):

There is an operation on Seifert surfaces defined by taking an arbitrary arc from the surface to itself with the arc interior embedded in the complement of the surface, and then adding a small tube to the surface along the arc. You can make an arbitrarily complicated Seifert surface for any knot this way. Perhaps more surprisingly, any two Seifert surfaces for the same knot are related to each other by a sequence of such moves and their inverses. So the Seifert surface is unique *up to this equivalence relation.*